# Can i debug my app xamarin.ios? crash on app launch in release version

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, cross-compiling, testflight

I wrote an app in xamarin on visual studio 2022.
The app works in debug mode but when i build the release and push in testfligth and dowload the app in my iphone x 17.0.2 crash on launch!

Can i debug or get a log file in release mode in xamarin.ios?

Here this is the log i found on mac when i launch the app in iphone create that, can you help me?

```
{"app_name":"SmartWinkApp.iOS","timestamp":"2023-11-14 09:43:08.00 +0100","app_version":"9.837","slice_uuid":"71324353-73d8-377f-8f4e-ab4234d6ec76","build_version":"1.0","platform":"2","bundleID":"com.tiemme.smartwinkprod","share_with_app_devs":"0","is_first_party":"0","bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)","roots_installed":"0","name":"SmartWinkApp.iOS","incident_id":"84920FF9-5BEE-4337-84D8-74E11C0AF9F1"}
{
"uptime": 120000,
"procRole": "Foreground",
"version": 2,
"userID": 501,
"deployVersion": 210,
"modelCode": "iPhone11,2",
"coalitionID": 2613,
"osVersion": {
"isEmbedded": true,
"train": "iPhone OS 17.1.1",
"releaseType": "User",
"build": "21B91"
},
"captureTime": "2023-11-14 09:43:04.9777 +0100",
"codeSigningMonitor": 1,
"incident": "84920FF9-5BEE-4337-84D8-74E11C0AF9F1",
"pid": 9096,
"cpuType": "ARM-64",
"roots_installed": 0,
"bug_type": "309",
"procLaunch": "2023-11-14 09:43:00.5065 +0100",
"procStartAbsTime": 3052599062069,
"procExitAbsTime": 3052706348922,
"procName": "SmartWinkApp.iOS",
"procPath": "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FABD6AEE-D970-4F63-BB7C-A7E1BD7A5009/SmartWinkApp.iOS.app/SmartWinkApp.iOS",
"bundleInfo": {
"CFBundleShortVersionString": "9.837",
"CFBundleVersion": "1.0",
"CFBundleIdentifier": "com.tiemme.smartwinkprod"
},
"storeInfo": {
"deviceIdentifierForVendor": "2DE0854B-705E-4E41-8B38-BAD624DC50D7",
"thirdParty": true
},
"parentProc": "launchd",
"parentPid": 1,
"coalitionName": "com.tiemme.smartwinkprod",
"crashReporterKey": "f79b4da96297d82b438336952350bb47bb5eaff3",
"lowPowerMode": 1,
"wasUnlockedSinceBoot": 1,
"isLocked": 0,
"codeSigningID": "com.tiemme.smartwinkprod",
"codeSigningTeamID": "CZGHK952JT",
"codeSigningFlags": 570434309,
"codeSigningValidationCategory": 3,
"codeSigningTrustLevel": 6,
"instructionByteStream": {
"beforePC": "fyMD1f17v6n9AwCR893/l78DAJH9e8Go/w9f1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==",
"atPC": "AwEAVH8jA9X9e7+p/QMAkejd/5e/AwCR/XvBqP8PX9bAA1/WfyMD1Q=="
},
"basebandVersion": "6.00.00",
"exception": {
"codes": "0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000",
"rawCodes": [
0,
0
],
"type": "EXC_CRASH",
"signal": "SIGABRT"
},
"termination": {
"flags": 0,
"code": 6,
"namespace": "SIGNAL",
"indicator": "Abort trap: 6",
"byProc": "SmartWinkApp.iOS",
"byPid": 9096
},
"asi": {
"libsystem_c.dylib": [
"abort() called"
]
},
"faultingThread": 0,
"threads": [
{
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 10000000
},
{
"value": 32
},
{
"value": 18446744069414585088
},
{
"value": 8261488141439977006
},
{
"value": 8261488136853917678
},
{
"value": 1000
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 4536224960
},
{
"value": 4537569147
},
{
"value": 96
},
{
"value": 2147483648
},
{
"value": 328
},
{
"value": 8387152320,
"symbolLocation": 0,
"symbol": "_main_thread"
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 6
},
{
"value": 259
},
{
"value": 8387152544,
"symbolLocation": 224,
"symbol": "_main_thread"
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 4555130368
},
{
"value": 4537569144
},
{
"value": 6129771904
},
{
"value": 1
},
{
"value": 4522574168
},
{
"value": 16777215
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 8800343680
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 1073741824
},
"fp": {
"value": 6129768256
},
"sp": {
"value": 6129768224
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8224362524,
"matchesCrashFrame": 1
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
},
"id": 1544130,
"triggered": true,
"name": "tid_103",
"queue": "com.apple.main-thread",
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 40988,
"symbol": "__pthread_kill",
"symbolLocation": 8,
"imageIndex": 3
},
{
"imageOffset": 22144,
"symbol": "pthread_kill",
"symbolLocation": 267,
"imageIndex": 4
},
{
"imageOffset": 482340,
"symbol": "__abort",
"symbolLocation": 135,
"imageIndex": 5
},
{
"imageOffset": 482204,
"symbol": "abort",
"symbolLocation": 191,
"imageIndex": 5
},
{
"imageOffset": 174267576,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172842276,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172404252,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172398576,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172356840,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 10967692,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 1122436,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 1122140,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 10192000,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172477408,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 173241260,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 173266612,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 172338928,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 174347412,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 1121600,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 24012,
"symbol": "start",
"symbolLocation": 2239,
"imageIndex": 6
}
]
},
{
"id": 1544149,
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 6652,
"symbol": "start_wqthread",
"symbolLocation": 0,
"imageIndex": 4
}
],
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 6130905088
},
{
"value": 5639
},
{
"value": 6130368512
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 409604
},
{
"value": 18446744073709551615
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 0
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 0
},
"fp": {
"value": 0
},
"sp": {
"value": 6130905088
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8800328188
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
}
},
{
"id": 1544150,
"name": "SGen worker",
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 260
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 161
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 6130331320
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 4522547592
},
{
"value": 2
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 305
},
{
"value": 6130331648
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 4522547568
},
{
"value": 4522547632
},
{
"value": 6130331872
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 1
},
{
"value": 256
},
{
"value": 4527521800
},
{
"value": 4522545152
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 8800325588
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 1610612736
},
"fp": {
"value": 6130331440
},
"sp": {
"value": 6130331296
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8224328572
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
},
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 7036,
"symbol": "__psynch_cvwait",
"symbolLocation": 8,
"imageIndex": 3
},
{
"imageOffset": 4052,
"symbol": "_pthread_cond_wait",
"symbolLocation": 1227,
"imageIndex": 4
},
{
"imageOffset": 173909460,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 9428,
"symbol": "_pthread_start",
"symbolLocation": 135,
"imageIndex": 4
},
{
"imageOffset": 6672,
"symbol": "thread_start",
"symbolLocation": 7,
"imageIndex": 4
}
]
},
{
"id": 1544154,
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 6652,
"symbol": "start_wqthread",
"symbolLocation": 0,
"imageIndex": 4
}
],
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 6131478528
},
{
"value": 8963
},
{
"value": 6130941952
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 409604
},
{
"value": 18446744073709551615
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 0
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 0
},
"fp": {
"value": 0
},
"sp": {
"value": 6131478528
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8800328188
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
}
},
{
"id": 1544155,
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 6652,
"symbol": "start_wqthread",
"symbolLocation": 0,
"imageIndex": 4
}
],
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 6132051968
},
{
"value": 9731
},
{
"value": 6131515392
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 409604
},
{
"value": 18446744073709551615
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 0
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 0
},
"fp": {
"value": 0
},
"sp": {
"value": 6132051968
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8800328188
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
}
},
{
"id": 1544157,
"name": "Finalizer",
"threadState": {
"x": [
{
"value": 14
},
{
"value": 1
},
{
"value": 4510652296
},
{
"value": 6134198362
},
{
"value": 6134197641
},
{
"value": 9
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 4522471424
},
{
"value": 4294967295
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 2
},
{
"value": 2
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 1099511627776
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 18446744073709551580
},
{
"value": 6134198272
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 1
},
{
"value": 1
},
{
"value": 4522574168
},
{
"value": 4522475344
},
{
"value": 0
},
{
"value": 6134198272
},
{
"value": 4522471424
},
{
"value": 4514357308
},
{
"value": 4522471424
},
{
"value": 4522471424
}
],
"flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
"lr": {
"value": 4509962540
},
"cpsr": {
"value": 1610612736
},
"fp": {
"value": 6134197968
},
"sp": {
"value": 6134197840
},
"esr": {
"value": 1442840704,
"description": " Address size fault"
},
"pc": {
"value": 8224325972
},
"far": {
"value": 0
}
},
"frames": [
{
"imageOffset": 4436,
"symbol": "semaphore_wait_trap",
"symbolLocation": 8,
"imageIndex": 3
},
{
"imageOffset": 172855596,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 173559556,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 173559176,
"imageIndex": 2
},
{
"imageOffset": 9428,
"symbol": "_pthread_start",
"symbolLocation": 135,
"imageIndex": 4
},
{
"imageOffset": 6672,
"symbol": "thread_start",
"symbolLocation": 7,
"imageIndex": 4
}
]
}
],
"usedImages": [
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64",
"base": 4540170240,
"size": 5832704,
"uuid": "a3389983-874b-3be0-b7de-eeb8a1de8bcb",
"path": "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FABD6AEE-D970-4F63-BB7C-A7E1BD7A5009/SmartWinkApp.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp",
"name": "libSkiaSharp"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64",
"base": 4533960704,
"size": 1261568,
"uuid": "9963a21c-847c-3340-9c75-6a1056a8a6b3",
"path": "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FABD6AEE-D970-4F63-BB7C-A7E1BD7A5009/SmartWinkApp.iOS.app/Frameworks/libHarfBuzzSharp.framework/libHarfBuzzSharp",
"name": "libHarfBuzzSharp"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64",
"base": 4337106944,
"size": 177700864,
"uuid": "71324353-73d8-377f-8f4e-ab4234d6ec76",
"path": "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FABD6AEE-D970-4F63-BB7C-A7E1BD7A5009/SmartWinkApp.iOS.app/SmartWinkApp.iOS",
"name": "SmartWinkApp.iOS"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64e",
"base": 8224321536,
"size": 233472,
"uuid": "77ac893d-8258-332b-9dfc-b7ba2439af97",
"path": "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
"name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64e",
"base": 8800321536,
"size": 49140,
"uuid": "810e428a-f26d-37bb-bb0f-609cbb4718c7",
"path": "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
"name": "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64e",
"base": 7162068992,
"size": 516084,
"uuid": "bdb2e656-dfd8-3f53-8384-d686e76fedcb",
"path": "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib",
"name": "libsystem_c.dylib"
},
{
"source": "P",
"arch": "arm64e",
"base": 7609290752,
"size": 555740,
"uuid": "a795ad37-6266-385e-95e6-c1ca804c926e",
"path": "/usr/lib/dyld",
"name": "dyld"
},
{
"size": 0,
"source": "A",
"base": 0,
"uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
],
"sharedCache": {
"base": 6896812032,
"size": 3494445056,
"uuid": "3334cefc-51e9-3eaf-a5aa-8e47501f35cb"
},
"vmSummary": "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.6G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.6G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=595.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=595.1M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           564.2M       60 \nMALLOC guard page                   64K        4 \nMALLOC_LARGE                        16K        1 \nSMOOTH                               24        2 \nSTACK GUARD                         96K        6 \nStack                             5264K        6 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       19.2M       26 \n__AUTH                            4615K      497 \n__AUTH_CONST                      45.7M     1001 \n__CTF                               824        1 \n__DATA                            29.2M      996 \n__DATA_CONST                      55.2M     1010 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      10.6M      911 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       377.1M        4 \n__OBJC_RO                         85.2M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2680K        1 \n__TEXT                             1.2G     1024 \ndyld private memory                272K        2 \nmapped file                      190.2M      195 \nshared memory                       80K        4 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.6G     5757 \n",
"legacyInfo": {
"threadTriggered": {
"name": "tid_103",
"queue": "com.apple.main-thread"
}
},
"logWritingSignature": "0826570d4ef78976f0e0b7320b614ab2d2921003",
"trialInfo": {
"rollouts": [
{
"rolloutId": "6081eda9c724863038027c4f",
"factorPackIds": {
"BIFROST_PROD_2": "6507ac53a476fd582f0a27b8"
},
"deploymentId": 240001050
},
{
"rolloutId": "6081ed9716bb6d61d81d5014",
"factorPackIds": {
"BIFROST_PROD_1": "654e6462553f07431fda6075"
},
"deploymentId": 240002871
}
],
"experiments": []
}
}
```

Comment: you can connect the device to your Mac and then search for Device Log, you can find your iOS device there and get logs

Comment: where can i find the "Device Log"?

Comment: Search it using the searchbar on the top right side in VS mac

Comment: i'm writing the code in windows pc with visual studio 2022 and i attach the mac to cross compile with the visual studio's tool, i connect iphone with the mac and i archive the app the app in windows. the log i see in the mac don't show me the crash

Comment: That's not possible, Device log literally captures everything are you sure you're doing it right?

Comment: this is my log crash file
we.tl/t-JpUXuUpfXw

Comment: Add it to the question